# How can I get all categories from the database in the header?

Tags: php, database, render

I have a `header.php` in which I have the top navigation. In this nav I have a dropdown menu which gives me all the categories that are in the database table `categories(id, category)`.

Here is the part of the header:

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">
  <a 
   href="http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories"
   title="Categories">
      Categories
  </a>
 </button>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <?php foreach ($categories as $cat): ?>
   <a 
    href="http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/
    <?php echo e($cat['category']); ?>">
     <?php echo e($cat->category);?>
  </a>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

The next function is in my CategoryRepository.php and gets all Categories from the database:

```
public function allCategories()
{
 $table = $this->getTableName();
 $model = $this->getModelName();

 $stmt = $this->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `$table`");
 $allCategories = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $model);
 return $allCategories;
}
```

I need this function for the foreach in the navigation, the problem is that I have to put following code:

```
$categories = $this->categoryRepository->allCategories();
```

In every function in the Controllers in which a new site for the blog is rendered; here is an example:

```
public function index()
{
 $categories = $this->categoryRepository->allCategories();
 $posts = $this->postsRepository->all(); 
 $this->render("post/index", [
  'posts' => $posts,
  'categories' => $categories,
 ]);
}
```

**Is there a possibility I'm not forced to put this code row in every function for a new site?**

I already tried to put it in the `__construct`, but somehow it didn't work.

Comment: are you using Symfony?

Comment: No; i Have made my own framework within a tutorial

Comment: What engine are you using for your template? Twig? A few days ago i was wondering how to do exactly the same thing like you, but using symfony, then i found "Embed controllers" in documentation in symfony. In short - render controller:action in your template file.

Comment: @D.Dimitrov I'm not using any template

Answer (score 0):

```
$fields = $this->db->list_fields($table); // gives you category `like(id, category,name)`
```

then you can manage what you need,

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
   $fields[$i] = str_replace('_', ' ', $fields[$i]);
   `$fields[$i] = ucwords($fields[$i]);`
}
return array('schema' => array_values($fields));
```

Comment: you can get all table fields name

Comment: Please explain what the code does, and how that solves the original problem. Please do so in the answer, not in the comment section, such that others can learn from your answer

Comment: and where should I put it?